# How to get Layer Objects by IDs

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script, jsx

Photoshop scripting API getting me struggled. It's not dev-friendly at all.
But still I believe, that there is a way to get layer object when I have layer id?

All I want to do is to duplicate selected layers to a new document. Layers might be nested within groups.

Comment: I have tried getting by name, but it doesn't find anything.
I have tried also play a little with Action Reference, but can't find good reference (and it seem to be overcomplicating simple things).

Comment: OK. I found script, that duplicates selected layers to all opened documents (http://www.cameronmcefee.com/photoshop-script-duplicate-to-all/). I can modificate it to fit my need. Still is it the only way? Quite complicated for such simple action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, such a simple action shouldn't be so complicated.
Try this:

```
var curDoc  = app.activeDocument;
var newDoc = app.documents.add(curDoc.width,curDoc.height,curDoc.resolution);//add a new doc with the same dimensions as the active one
app.activeDocument = curDoc;//set the original doc as active
try {
    var curLayer = newDoc.activeLayer;//get a reference to the new document's current layer
    curDoc.activeLayer.duplicate(newDoc,ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);//dupliate the active layer from the original doc to the new/copy doc
} catch(e) {    alert(e);   }
```

If it helps, Photshop ships with a reference(which should be in `PHOTOSHOP_INSTALL_FOLDER/Scripting/Documents`) and/or the Object Model Viewer (visible under the Help menu in ExtendScriptToolkit).

Comment: That works for me :) Problem with doc is that many of these functions are just not working in my case. I am trying couple ways and recieve "This functionality might not be available in this version of program".

Comment: What version of Photoshop are you using ? I've tested with CS5.1 Maybe the API is slightly for your version. If that's the case, isolate the function that throws the error (could be `duplicate()`) and check the signature in the documentation for your version of Photoshop

Comment: I am using CS6 Trial (it matters that it's trial?).

Comment: I don't think it matters that it's trial. I'm slightly confused, the whole code above works ? Where does the "This functionality might not be available in this version of program" come from ? By doc do you mean a variable referencing a Photoshop document or documentation ?

Comment: Code above works perfectly. "doc" stands for "documentation".
But for example function Document.saveAs throws such exception. And not only this function.